# Loop through object AFTER a particular element?

Tags: loops, object

If you have an object

```
{"54":{name:Shaun, Age:102}, "21":{name:Alexis, Age:21} ...etc }
```

How do you loop through from AFTER "54", or after any particular element?

Thanks for your time and help.